# Get node with highest value in XPath

Tags: xpath

I have an XML about PC components and I need to get the most expensive one. So, in that case I would need to get the node with highest value(price).

`XML:`

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Motherboard</name>
    <price>150</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>CPU</name>
    <price>300</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>RAM</name>
    <price>45</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

That is what I have tried so far:

This returns 300 which is correct:

`max(/products/product/price)`

**Result:**

[image]

But when I try to get the most expensive product, the expression I am using to achieve it does not work:

`/products/product[max(price)]`

**Result:**

[image]

The expected result should be this one:

```
<product>
  <name>CPU</name>
  <price>300</price>
</product>
```

I am using this [online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 products/product[price= max(/products/product/price)]
```

will do :)

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 solution :

```
//product[not(price<//price)]
```

https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester